# How to disable or apply custom menu to GTK (PyGTK) Notebook pages?

Tags: menu, gtk, pygtk, customization

I am trying to apply custom menu to tab pages on my notebook control. I need to be able to select certain specific action for the entire page and i figured the tab label would be the best place to start.

So, i created a **EventBox**, applied **Label** as its child, and bound event callbacks to *button-pressed-event* and it... works.. kindof.

What i get is two menus: one is the one I create, and on top of it - the one created by GTK Notebook. to select something from my custom menu i need to *escape* the notebook menu first, and i certainly don't like it.

so the question is: how do I disable gtk notebook menus? or how can i set my own, custom menu, with my own, custom callbacks? I don't want to list all the available tab pages in the menu - it's introducing too much noise, so adding menu labels to the existing menu is not really the way to go.

thanks bunches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GtkNotebook should only show the tab selector if [enable-popup](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/unstable/GtkNotebook.html#GtkNotebook--enable-popup) is true. It defaults to false, so you've probably enabled it by mistake.

Comment: thanks! i had no references to that in sources, but the glade file had the flag set.